# Bottom Bar overlay outside navagationview

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-navigationview

I am creating a UI from a mockup that looks like this.
[image: The UI]
You can see the bottom bar is over the navigation view but not over the sidebar. I want to make the bottom bar outside the navigation view so it does not create a new instance for every view.

Is there any way to do this while supporting macos v11.

Comment: To make it easier to answer your question, please create a [mcve] showing what you've tried, and what didn't work.

Comment: You can create some RootView, which has NavigationView on the top and BottomView on the bottom (if I understand your question correctly)